# stitch rawvideo with ffmpeg - Picture size 0x0 is invalid

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a timelapse video from several images that I'm fetching from a website. In order to make this faster, my plan was split the workload between multiple cores, each fetching their respective frames (I'm streaming the images to ffmpeg stdin):

`ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -f rawvideo part_N`

Then I wanted to stitch the rawvideo parts to an mp4:

`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -i part_0 -f rawvideo -i part_1 ... output.mp4`

But I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> Picture size 0x0 is invalid`
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`rawvideo` has no metadata so you have to supply all parameters. Since your input is mjpeg (**edit**: sequence), just keep it as that.

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -c copy -f mjpeg part_N
```

Generate a text file like this

```
file part_0
file part_1
file part_2
...
file part_N
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -r 30 -i list.txt output.mp4
```

here `-r` is the desired framerate. Default is 25.

Comment: I'm getting `part_%d: No such file or directory`. Also tried `%3d` and `%03d`, and enclosed in single quotes, same results

Comment: Save to part_N.jpg and then input part_%d.jpg

Comment: saving it as .jpg causes the output video to only contain the first frame of each

Comment: Edited answer with new cmd.